# Progress bar c++

Tags: c++, windows, console-application

I'm creating a simple server console application. This server works on Windows.

I'd like to make a progress bar and print it while server is sending files to the client. But I don't know how to implement it using winapi.

Could someone explain ?

Comment: ***Could someone explain ?*** It's impossible to begin when we don't know what api / framework you are using. I assume you mean winapi. Or are you using some other framework like Qt or mfc or wxwidgets?

Comment: Yes, I mean winapi

Comment: It's console application

Comment: I was going to add winapi as a tag but then you said console application. For that I assume you want some type of text progress bar perhaps using an increasing number of stars.

Comment: @drescherjm It is possible to utilize WinAPI calls from a console application. Even paint on it. The practicality of it is up for debate.

Comment: Yes, you can make a GUI window in a console application. I set the linker setting for my GUI Qt applications in debug mode as subsystem:console so I can see the stdout without extra code.

Comment: I'd go for a text-based progress bar.  Using printf.  hint: '\b' is back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write on the same line of the console using the carriage return (\r). With this technique you can basically override the old progress an print the new one, which results in a "moving" progressbar. This works independent of any api, just with c++ and it worked on the windows console.

```
int barLength = 30;
int pos = progress * barLength;

std::cout << "[";
for(int i=0; i != barLength; ++i)
{
    if(i < pos)
        std::cout << "#";
    else
        std::cout << " ";
}
std::cout << "]\r";
```

You get the concept and can adapt the look to your needs.
Just pass the progress value as double to this (100% = 1.0).
It might be useful to write a part, if the progress is 1.0, so that a complete bar is printed with a \n or std::endl at the end.

Comment: How to count `progress` if I have size of file which is sending to the client ?

Comment: You need to keep track of the amount of bytes, which you already sent. Then it's simply sentBytes/totalBytes ( or any other unit you are counting in)

Comment: Thanks very much)